# Secure never expiring tokens? How to handle multiple devices?

Tags: android, authentication

**What I have:**

I am having an Android application with an auth but no password or username. When the app Starts it Creates a New Account over a Server.  The Server sends back the Auth Token which is accountid and random String hashed together. To validate that is not a bis Problem.

**Problems:**

There are 2 Problems First the Client saves the token in a tXT File and everyone with that token can auth so it is very unsecured. The second Problem is that I can't log in on 2 Devices. I thinks I Could link the Account with faceBookmarks or an Google Account but I only what that one device AT a time connects to the Server and I don't know how to check that! Example Tom and Jim are playing on Different Devices and Different Accounts it Works but if There using to same Account the can not play AT the Same time.

I hope you understand my questions!

**Update**

I fixes Problem one Put I still didn't find a solution for Problem one. I need a way to Store a token even if the app is closed or the device restarts. I tried it with Text Files but no crypto was good. Base64 can simply revert to normal text, md5 is not readable for the app and crypto with Keys I need to save the key and have the Same problem.

Comment: Maybe the keystore (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) or account manager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) would be suitable for storing the token.